# Отладчик node js с древовидным выводом времени выполнения функций?

Tags: node.js, профилирование

Есть потребность оптимизировать участок кода.

Вызываю функцию и засекаю время её исполнения.

```
var startTime = new Date;

myFunction(function(){
  console.log('Прошло времени: ' + ((new Date - startTime) + "мс.") );
});
```

Есть ли удобные средства для отладки кода с выводом в древовидном виде всех вызываемых функций (профилирование), который вызываются при работе myFunction  и времени их работы по убыванию?

Я помню в visual studio на С++ был такой инструмент удобный, что сразу было видно где узкие места в производительности. То есть показывает функцию func1 и 97% времени выполнения, я её раскрываю и там вижу что эта func1 вызывает childFunc1 (92%) и childFunc2 (8%), раскрываю childFunc1 и опять вижу какие функции в ней вызываются чаще всего. Было очень удобно оптимизировать код.
Работаю с siblime, но для отладки готов использовать любую другую среду разработки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отладки можно использовать возможность [профилирования процессора](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/node-js-profiling-in-webstorm-part-1-cpu-profiling/) в [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

Comment: Автор вопроса запросил отладку в ноде а не в браузере